# Auto scroll listing on marker click in mapbox

Tags: javascript, mapbox, autoscroll

I created a map with Mapbox.js and have been trying to figure out how to autoscroll a listing after I click on the associated marker.  I am able to activate the listing on marker click but I would like the scroll bar to auto scroll to the listing destination in the sidebar.  Any help would be greatly appreciated. [Here](https://99026c5ff8423ea802ef95931a62ceb8c40a55f3.googledrive.com/host/0B3GkHx7_68-IfnVvcG5GVXFWYjhiaHgtWVFxcEpkV1htMVBNcEktZ3U0WS1NOFFJZUFLbkU/WV.html) is a link to the map

Here is the code snippet where I activate the listing on marker click:

```
locale.on('click', function(e) {
  setActive(listing);
  locale.openPopup();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet below solved my problem with auto-scrolling a listing after marker click:

```
 listing.scrollIntoView(true);
```